# How to find this url in the html with php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, file-get-contents

I want to find a specific url in a html page and get it's part.
the url is in this page :

```
http://site1.com/games/arcade/139173-angry-birds-friends-1-7-0.html`
```

and is like

```
http://download.site2.org/?server=2&apkid=com.rovio.angrybirdsfriends&ver=1.7.0
```

I want 3 parts of it:

1. 2
2. com.rovio.angrybirdsfriends
3. 1.7.0

My code:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://site1.com/games/name/139173-angry-birds-friends-1-7-0.html");
preg_match("/download(.*)/", $html, $results)
echo = $results[0];
```

Comment: mistake #1: using regexes to parse html. use a dom parser.

Comment: From what should the `2` be parsed in the first example?

Comment: url is in $html = file_get_contents("http://site1.com/games/name/139173-angry-birds-friends-1-7-0.html");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$url = 'http://download.site2.org/?server=2&apkid=com.rovio.angrybirdsfriends&ver=1.7.0';

$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $params);

echo $params['server'], PHP_EOL;
echo $params['apkid'], PHP_EOL;
echo $params['ver'], PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
2
com.rovio.angrybirdsfriends
1.7.0
```

**Update**

```
// Read HTML
$html = file_get_contents(
    'http://getandroidapp.org/games/arcade/'
    . '139173-angry-birds-friends-1-7-0.html'
);

// Turn HTML into a DOM document
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html); // Mute warnings

// Find anchor ...
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');

    // ... having a query part that starts with 'server='
    if (preg_match('#\?server=#', $href)) {
        $url = $href;

        // Parse query string from href
        $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
        parse_str($query, $params);

        // Display values
        echo $params['server'], PHP_EOL;
        echo $params['apkid'], PHP_EOL;
        echo $params['ver'], PHP_EOL;

        // One is enough
        break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2
com.rovio.angrybirdsfriends
1.7.0
```

It is not totally fool-proof but maybe good enough in your case.

Comment: yes, but first i should find the url in html file, http://download.site2.org/?server=*&apkid=*&ver=* . only * change every time in http://site1.com/games/arcade/139173-angry-birds-friends-1-7-0.html

Comment: I cannot reach `http://site1.com/games/arcade/139173-angry-birds-friends-1-7-0.html` and therefore I can't see what the HTML looks like. If you could post a relevant portion of that file, then I may be able to help you parse it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look